# Add hidden meta data to product Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've added a custom field to my product for admin only meta data, I have hidden it using CSS.

However it still shows up in emails. Is there any way I can create a custom field where the meta data only shows up in the admin orders page?

Comment: You can also hide it with CSS in emails using this email-styles.php template in your active theme: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/ … This is going to be the simplest and fastest way. *(You can use also a woocommerce test email plugin to better target the css and to see it in action)*.

Comment: I tried that but they get put into a table with no id or class, so I have no way of applying css to them.

Comment: used a preview plugin, it;s even worse than I thought. The meta data is just straight dumped as text in a td tag, so I can't select the one I wish to hide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use **`woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields`** filter hook to remove this custom field from order metadata, using **`unset()`** php function this way:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields', 'wc_email_order_meta_remove_custom_field', 10, 3 );
function wc_email_order_meta_remove_custom_field( $fields, $sent_to_admin, $order ) {
    // Replace HERE 'meta_key' by your custom field meta key or slug.
    unset($fields['meta_key']);

    return $fields;
}
```

*This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This should work, but not sure as you don't provide any information and code related to the way you have set this custom field.